# How to select different properties of a generic Queryable using lamda

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I have this method to dynamically query on a generic Queryable:

```
protected virtual async Task<IList<T>> GetQueryableAsync<T>(
    Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null,
    Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null,
    string includeProperties = null,
    string columns = null,
    int? skip = null,
    int? take = null)
    where T : class
{
    using (var context = _factory.Invoke())
    {
        includeProperties = includeProperties ?? string.Empty;
        columns = columns ?? string.Empty;
        var colArray = columns.Split
            (new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        IQueryable<T> query = context.Set<T>();

        if (filter != null)
        {
            query = query.Where(filter);
        }

        foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split
            (new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        {
            query = query.Include(includeProperty);
        }

        if (orderBy != null)
        {
            query = orderBy(query);
        }

        if (skip.HasValue)
        {
            query = query.Skip(skip.Value);
        }

        if (take.HasValue)
        {
            query = query.Take(take.Value);
        }
        if (columns.Split
            (new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Count() > 0)
        {
             // Select specified columns from query
        }
        return await query.ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

I want to select passed column names by `columns` parameter. The result query should be of type IQueryable. I have tried different approaches but no one applies on generic types.
I have tied this class:

```
public static class ExpressionTreeHelper
{
    /// <summary> Returns an IEnumerable of anonymous type defined by <paramref name="properties"/>. </summary>
    public static IQueryable<T> SelectDynamic<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, params string[] properties)
    {
        return SelectProperties<T>(source.AsQueryable(), properties).Cast<T>();
    }

    private static IQueryable SelectProperties<T>(this IQueryable<T> queryable, IEnumerable<string> propertyNames)
    {
        // get propertyinfo's from original type
        var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(p => propertyNames.Contains(p.Name));

        // Create the x => expression
        var lambdaParameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
        // Create the x.<propertyName>'s
        var propertyExpressions = properties.Select(p => Expression.Property(lambdaParameterExpression, p));

        // Creating anonymous type using dictionary of property name and property type
        var anonymousType = AnonymousTypeUtils.CreateType(properties.ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p => p.PropertyType));
        var anonymousTypeConstructor = anonymousType.GetConstructors().Single();
        var anonymousTypeMembers = anonymousType.GetProperties().Cast<MemberInfo>().ToArray();

        // Create the new {} expression using 
        var anonymousTypeNewExpression = Expression.New(anonymousTypeConstructor, propertyExpressions, anonymousTypeMembers);

        var selectLambdaMethod = GetExpressionLambdaMethod(lambdaParameterExpression.Type, anonymousType);
        var selectBodyLambdaParameters = new object[] { anonymousTypeNewExpression, new[] { lambdaParameterExpression } };
        var selectBodyLambdaExpression = (LambdaExpression)selectLambdaMethod.Invoke(null, selectBodyLambdaParameters);

        var selectMethod = GetQueryableSelectMethod(typeof(T), anonymousType);
        var selectedQueryable = selectMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { queryable, selectBodyLambdaExpression }) as IQueryable;
        return selectedQueryable;
    }

    private static MethodInfo GetExpressionLambdaMethod(Type entityType, Type funcReturnType)
    {
        var prototypeLambdaMethod = GetStaticMethod(() => Expression.Lambda<Func<object, object>>(default(Expression), default(IEnumerable<ParameterExpression>)));
        var lambdaGenericMethodDefinition = prototypeLambdaMethod.GetGenericMethodDefinition();
        var funcType = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(entityType, funcReturnType);
        var lambdaMethod = lambdaGenericMethodDefinition.MakeGenericMethod(funcType);
        return lambdaMethod;
    }

    private static MethodInfo GetQueryableSelectMethod(Type entityType, Type returnType)
    {
        var prototypeSelectMethod = GetStaticMethod(() => Queryable.Select(default(IQueryable<object>), default(Expression<Func<object, object>>)));
        var selectGenericMethodDefinition = prototypeSelectMethod.GetGenericMethodDefinition();
        return selectGenericMethodDefinition.MakeGenericMethod(entityType, returnType);
    }

    private static MethodInfo GetStaticMethod(Expression<Action> expression)
    {
        var lambda = expression as LambdaExpression;
        var methodCallExpression = lambda.Body as MethodCallExpression;
        return methodCallExpression.Method;
    }
}
```

but as this class returns `IQueryable<dynamic>` I have problem with casting it to `IQueryable<T>`

Comment: This is a very complex thing to achieve, but it might just be easier if you pass in a `Select` expression instead.

Comment: Since the method queries `T` and returns `T`s, you cannot select individual columns anyway. That would require you to return another type.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Well, technically you could return T with only some properties populated, but yes, that's why I suggested a select expression.

Comment: That's the point, I just want to populate certain fields

Comment: You can still pass in an `Expression<Func<T, T>>` though, and let the caller decide how to create that.

Comment: This would require selecting an anonymous type and then create a `T` and assign it these values. `.Select(t => new { c1 t.col1, c2 = t.col2 }).AsEnumerable().Select(a => new T{ col1 = a.c1, col2 = a.c2 })`. Something like this where `AsEnumerable()` ends the EF (or whatever provider) part.

Comment: Seems like there's a lot of bending and twisting going on just so the arguments are string-typed rather than strong typed. I'm guessing this is due to some component further down the line that uses strings (perhaps some UI component that doesn't know .NET? Might be good information to have as a constraint on answers so that we don't spend time trying to find other ways of solving the problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest that you change the code to take a `Expression<Func<T, T>>` instead of a list of strings. There are a few reasons for this:

- It's a lot simpler and easier to read.
- It has compile-time type safety - imagine if you rename a column, your code would break but you wouldn't know until later.

For example:

```
Task<IList<T>> GetQueryableAsync<T>(..., Expression<Func<T, T>> selector)
{
    // snip

    return await query
        .Select(selector)
        .ToListAsync();
}
```

And then call it like this:

```
var result = await GetQueryableAsync(..., x => new MyEntity { Id = x.Id });
```